# Rsync from remote machine to local windows machine

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, rsync

I am trying to copy a directory from a remote server into my local machine thats running windows, but I am having trouble on how to specify the windows path that includes the C: drive

```
rsync -avzh vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/home/someDir ***C:/users/etc....***
```

What would be the correct way of specifying the destination path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync doesn't know anything about Windows. It needs a 'fake' unix-style path like this:
`/cygdrive/c/users/etc`

This path looks as though it must be for unix applications installed under [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com) but it seems this also applies to other versions of rsync.

Comment: Yeah I know this works but I am trying to avoid cygwin for the project's purpose. I'll accept this answer as it is valid and I have found an alternate file syncing solution.

Comment: I don't remember where I got this rsync – it uses this path style even though I never had cygwin.  I'd be interested to know about your alternative sync solution.

Comment: I'm using shared folders between vagrant and virtualbox.